# NotFoundHttpException Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am very new in learning Laravel. I want to fetch data from a database and show it. I can do it. But I want to use the title (fetched from the database) as a link. but then I get a NotFoundHttpException.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index');
Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');
```

**Controller**

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::all();

        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
    }

    public function show($id){
        $article = Article::find($id);

        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('new_welcome')
@section('content')
<h1>Articles</h1>
    @foreach($articles as $article)
        <article>
            <h2>
                <a href="{url ('/articles',$article->id)}">{{$article->title}}</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="body">{{ $article->body}}</div>
       </article>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Can someone help me in this case?

Comment: For one, you have 3 `return` statements in your `index()` function...

Comment: The error means it cannot find the route, what is the URL you are entering?

Comment: For two, you don't have a route defined to show an individual `article`, which is where that `NotFoundHttpException` would come from.

Comment: For three, make sure the value you use as a URL parameter is unique in the database. Using an article's `name` may lead to issues in pulling the wrong record.

Comment: I have a route to show individual article. I have edited my post

Comment: @DavidNguyen When I give the URL 
"http://homestead.app/articles" it can show me all the articles title along with body.then if I click on any single article title then it can not show me the specific article. 
But, if I give the URL "http://homestead.app/articles/2" it will show the second article.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because of You've "eat" one curly brace (blade engine skips it):

was:

```
href="{url ('/articles',$article->id)}"
```

have to be:

```
href="{{url ('/articles',$article->id)}}"
```

as You said:

> if I click on any single article title then it can not show me the
>   specific article. But, if I give the URL "homestead.app/articles/2";

so You can see that when You click on link Your browser's address bar becomes:

```
homestead.app/{url ('/articles',$article->id)}
```

Because You're beginner so I'll give You advice to not to set direct url in views using `url()` helper.

Named routes are better if You want to have app that will work properly if in future You decide to change url from: `articles` to `artcls`. In this named routes will save You from bulk changing urls in view files.

set name to Your route using `'as'` directive that makes Your routing flexible for changes (when You need to change URL so You change only path and keep views unchanged):

```
Route::get('articles/{id}', ['as' => 'article', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@show']);
Route::get('articles', ['as' => 'articles', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@index']);
```

change Your view file (find `route` helper in href):

```
@extends('new_welcome')
@section('content')
    <h1> Articles </h1>

    @foreach($articles as $article)
        <article>
            <h2>

                <a href="{{ route('article', $article->id) }}">{{$article->title}}</a>

            </h2>
            <div class="body">{{ $article->body}}</div>
        </article>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Comment: seems like Your web server does not rewrite properly

Comment: may I show you the URL that I get after clicking any specific article?

Comment: @Tasmin it cannot be have You done all of stuff that I've wrote?

Comment: @Tasmin look at href part, You've "eat" one curly brace {  that is not parsable by blade

Comment: This does not help too.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Restarted my browser it worked.!!!!!! I don't know why.

Comment: because You've not refreshed page of articles after changing code (:

Comment: No I did this. I did this dear :) BTW my code is the same that I posted. But now it works :\